# Spotty Internet in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS/Doesnt see ethernet

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet, ethernet

So I had to redownload ubuntu, and after I did the internet became very spotty. I tried connecting my ethernet cable, but the computer doesn't seem to see it.

```
iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enx9cebe80672d3  no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"University House Midtown"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.24 GHz  Access Point:D4:68:4D:2A:C3:AC   
      Bit Rate=162 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0


sudo ethtool enx9cebe80672d3 | grep Link
Link deteceted: no
```

and sometimes, when I try to check the internet, this is what showes up

```
ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

but other times its just normal like this:

```
ping google.com
64 bytes from yv-in-f101.1e100.net (74.125.21.101): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=2.06 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f101.1e100.net (74.125.21.101): icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=3.12 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f101.1e100.net (74.125.21.101): icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=2.80 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f101.1e100.net (74.125.21.101): icmp_seq=4 ttl=49 time=2.41 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f101.1e100.net (74.125.21.101): icmp_seq=5 ttl=49 time=2.07 ms
64 bytes from yv-in-f101.1e100.net (74.125.21.101): icmp_seq=6 ttl=49 time=2.07 ms
```

While posting this question, my internet disappeared again. The connection is very spotty, sometimes works and sometimes doesnt.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Connect via ethernet. Then go to the network icon in the top panel and choose `Connection Information`. Note what driver is being used for your ethernet connection. If it's r8169, that might explain your problem, as it's kind of buggy.

Install `r8168-dkms`, reboot the computer, bring up your BIOS, and turn off `secure boot` in your BIOS.

For wireless problems, in terminal, type `sudo iwconfig power off` to turn off power management. And make sure that your connection is using `WPA2-AES`.

Let me know if that helps. Cheers, Al